# Game Center Sandbox : "Could not create game" issue

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit

I'm currently developing a turn based game using Game Center to handle the online functionalities (for matchmaking and turns handling).

I'm using two sandbox accounts - one on my 3gs and one on the ios Simulator.
I've been testing my app using the GKTurnBasedMatchMakerViewController to do the match making for a while without any problems, but I'm now stuck with an issue:

Every time I want to invite another player for a new (with either one or the other player), the GKTurnBasedMatchMakerViewController displays a UIAlertView stating :

> Could not create game - Please remove an existing game and try again.

The thing is, I've deleted all the matches for each player (none of them has any game in his list (not even a closed game). So none of the user is in any match at the moment.

In my GKTurnBaseMatchMakerViewControllerDelegate the *turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFailWithError:* is not called.
The only called function called in the delegate- when I click the OK button on the UIAlertView - is *turnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:*

The only thing I can think of is that my games are actually not removed from GameCenter, but as I'm removing them using the GKMatchMakerViewController UI, I barely think so.

---

When quitting from a turn-based match I've implemented the *turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:playerQuitForMatch:* like this:

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController playerQuitForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
  if ( [self isLocalPlayerCurrentPlayerForMatch:match] ) {

    NSData* endData = match.matchData;

    for (GKTurnBasedParticipant* participant in match.participants) {
      participant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
    }
    match.currentParticipant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;

    [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:endData 
                     completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                       if (error) {
                         NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                       }
                     }];
  }  

}
```

*(NB: I only have two players in the game)*

where isLocalPlayerCurrentPlayerForMatch is:

```
- (BOOL) isLocalPlayerCurrentPlayerForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch*)match
{
  return [[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] playerID] isEqualToString:match.currentParticipant.playerID];
}
```

Has anyone encountered and found a solution to this issue?
Am I doing something wrong here, or is it so obvious I just can't see it?

Thank you very much for any comments that would help me find the root of that issue.

### Update

Thanks to @kaan-dedeoglu I managed to know that both users had an empty list of matches (consistent with the displayed state).

I also created a third Sandbox account.
Naming the two first accounts A and B, C the third one.

State 1:

> 1. A and B are not linked to any match.
> 2. A and B are both getting the "Could not create game" error while creating any game (A invites B, A||B invites other player, A||B creates new automatch).

State 2:

> 1. C (working account) can invite B and normally plays a party with B.
> 2. C (working) can invite B for another simultaneous party
> 3. C (working) invites A to play.
> 4. A can't play (can't access the list of current matches, the GKTurnBasedMatchMakerViewController directly goes to the creation of a new game).
> 5. C is not working anymore.
> 6. A, B and C are now stuck in "Could not create game" error.

As a complement here is how I initialize my GKTurnBasedMatchMakerViewController, but I don't see that being wrong.

```
- (void) displayMatchMakerVC
{

  if (! [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated] ) return;

  GKMatchRequest* request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
  int nbPlayers = 2;
  request.minPlayers = nbPlayers;
  request.maxPlayers = nbPlayers;


  GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController*  matchMakerVC = [[[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
  matchMakerVC.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;
  matchMakerVC.showExistingMatches = YES;

  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:matchMakerVC animated:YES];
}
```

NB: I'm not using ARC, could that be related to a memory issue? I'm not really a memory management guru, but it *seems* correct to my understanding.

Any idea of how this could be related to my code and not to game center?
Thank you very much for any answer that could help me go further.

### Update 2: turnbasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatchMethod:

Here's my turnbasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatchMethod: method.

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
  BLTheme* theme = [[[BLGameConfig sharedConfig] localPlayer] userTheme];
  GameSceneRemoteGCLoader* loader = [[GameSceneRemoteGCLoader alloc] initWithGKMatch:match andTheme:theme];
  [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:loader];

}
```

When I'm launching an automatch it's launching the exact same error "Could not create game - Please remove an existing game and try again.".

Comment: a few questions regarding your update. What happens when you start games with auto match - i.e. just hitting 'Play' without inviting anyone. Also, can I see your "turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:" implementation?

Comment: When I start an automatch I'm getting the same "Could not create game error".

Updated my post again to show the turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch.
thanks for the help, very much appreciated.

Comment: After your 2nd edit. I'm pretty much lost too. The portions of code you've shared looks pretty good. I don't know why you're getting an error. I assume that turnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDidFindMatch method doesn't even get called. Sandbox mode can act weird at times. My last suggestion would be to log out and log-in and try removing all games with (using my answer). I wish I could be of more help!!

Comment: You're right, it's not even called.
I used your answer to remove them, but it didn't fix my issue either.
I'm also inclined to think that it might be sandbox related since it seems to be only related to my first two accounts, but I don't have any formal evidence to support that.
I'll come back and post if I get an answer or more elements.
Thank you very much for the help given and the time spent! :)

Comment: @thib_b , did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem and have not been able to find a solution. I have a suspicion that when I update builds, old matches are hidden from the new build but they aren't actually deleted, and I have too many matches *somewhere* which causes the error message to appear.

Comment: @TimArnold , I'm over that project, but I remember never really finding a solution to this (and just using new accounts when some were blocked...). That said, your point rings a bell and is interesting, but I'm sorry I can't help you more. Please post if you do find an answer. Cheers!

Comment: @thib_b I did find a solution to this problem, an Apple dev forums post linked from a StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14147258/1148702 . In short: games associated with an app but excluded from the match list because their CFBundleVersion (build number) differed count towards the ~30 game maximum. Tweaking Group / multiplayer Game Center settings in iTunes Connect, or deleting matches with other CFBundleVersion values, did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be the solution to your problem, but I had a similar issue and solved it in the following way.

It seems that either by default, or somehow, Game Center treats apps with differing `CFBundleVersion` (build number, not version number, or `CFBundleShortVersionString`) values as incompatible with one another, and thus does not show matches between apps with incremented build numbers. (Often, developers increment this number as new ad hoc builds or stable releases are distributed during development, so this is quite unfortunate).

To find and remove the "missing" games, I decremented my `CFBundleVersion` value (which revealed the games), and then deleted the offending matches.

Alternatively, tweaking some settings in iTunes Connect seems to have removed this `CFBundleVersion` incompatibility. It takes a while to propagate, but I think what did it was tapping on my app, tapping on View Details, making sure the Game Center switch is set to "Enabled", and making sure there is an item in the "Multiplayer Compatibility" table. You could also play with the possibilities within the "Manage Game Center" button from the original app screen, but I think the "Multiplayer Compatibility" setting is what finally allowed me to see all the "old" matches that were previously hidden.

Good luck!

Comment: I can't test your solution anymore, but as this solved this particular issue for you, I will mark it as the resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure: In both these devices, add these lines in your authentication completion handler and run it once. (then you can comment it out).

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:(^)(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {

   for (GKTurnbasedMatch *match in matches) {

       [match removeWithCompletionHandler:NULL];

    }
}];
```

This will ensure that all games are removed from your playerID.

Comment: thank you very much. Your code allowed me to check that there were no match (empty list, neither errors retrieving them). 
Updated my post if you feel like going further.
Thanks very much anyway! :)

Comment: This call does not remove all games from the local playerID. Please see GKTurnBasedMatch Class Reference on the method removeWithCompletionHandler --> "It is a programming error to call this method on a match that has the local player as an active participant."

Comment: @JayHaase yes on a release version, you should first pass your turn to the next player and then remove match (or else the match is stuck). However when debugging, it's fine to run this code on all devices - and this way the match is removed from game center servers (since every single participant removes the match.)

Comment: it will not remove quit matches. how can I remove quit matches in ios6

Answer (score 0):

It's ridiculous . You don't have to remove an existing match to create a new match. I'm developing a game like this and it actually works.

Comment: There does seem to be a limit on the number of `GKTurnBasedMatch`'s that are allowed for an app on Game Center.

Comment: Yes that's 30 for in-progress matches. But there can be more with not in-progress ones.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.  First I ran the app on the device for each player, calling quitAllMatches.  Then I ran the app again on each device, calling removeAllMatches.

In the long run, it has to be better to clean them up as you go along.  But this solved the immediate problem.

```
-(void) quitAllMatches {
    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* matches, NSError* error)  {
        for (GKTurnBasedMatch* match in matches) {
            GKTurnBasedParticipant* participant = match.currentParticipant;
            NSString* playerID = participant.playerID;
            NSString* localPlayerID = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID;
            if ([playerID isEqualToString: localPlayerID]) {
                NSArray* participants = match.participants;
                for (GKTurnBasedParticipant* participant in participants) {
                    participant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
                }
                NSData* data = [NSData data];
                [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData: data completionHandler:^(NSError* error) {
                    if (error) {
                        WJLog(@"did not end -- error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else {
                        WJLog(@"match ended!");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}

-(void) removeAllMatches {
    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* matches, NSError* error)  {
        for (GKTurnBasedMatch* match in matches) {
            [match removeWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError* error) {
                if (error) {
                    WJLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else {
                    WJLog(@"removed match");
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: It not removing quit matches. can you say how to remove quit matches in ios6.